# Account already disabled - Change Default Account

Tags: google-account, google-multi-login

My Default Account was my work account. I am now retired, so that account has already been disabled by my former employer, but when I sign in to Google, it appears as my 1st choice.

In all of the things I've read, you must be signed in to the account in order to change signing in preference. How can I do this when it is already deactivated & I no longer have access?

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

In a web browser, try to sign out of your accounts, then sign in again with the account that you want to use as the new default account.

## Explanation

In a web browser, when you sign in to multiple accounts the information is stored in cookies and the web pages and their resources could be stored in the cache. By signing out, the cookies should be cleared. If this doesn't work try to clear the cache and delete the cookies.

### Remarks

From [Sign in to multiple accounts at once](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977?hl=en)

> #### What a default account is
>
> In many cases, your default account is the one you signed in with first. On mobile devices, your default account can vary depending on your device's operating system and the apps you use.